My wife wants to have sex with my 1 year old present, I dont. She gets mad at me, what can I do?
I have a one year old son that sleeps in the bed with me and my wife. When he's asleep she tries to have sex with me but I will not do it. I feel it's weird and I'm too busy looking at him trying to make sure he doesn't wake up and see us, it's just not cool.
How can I best handle this situation?

There are lots of places other than your bed where you can be intimate. Maybe you can suggest some other options to her?

I've tried to rewrite it so its a better fit for this site, but I think this should be moved to https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Serious sidenote: why is a one year old still sleeping in the bed with you?

This is not a parenting question, but an interpersonal one, so I'll migrate it over, and it may get the answers you hope for.

First of all let me make very clear that nobody should be forced or shamed into anything they do not want. If you do not feel comfortable with the situation this is a legit reason for you to reject her advances. It's how you feel, nothing wrong or right about that.
However, only a handful of decades in the past (at least in rural Germany), it was common for families to sleep together in the same room. Older children often witnessed the conception of their siblings. I'm not saying that's a good thing per se, but having been the case for centuries, it's probably not as weird or wrong as it might feel.
While I wouldn't be comfortable with my child being awake in the same bed and witnessing it, I don't see anything strange about it if the child is fast asleep. Maybe it will help you to discuss with your wife the circumstances and conditions you feel comfortable with. For example, that your son lies in a co-sleeper and not on the same mattress as you and that noises and movements are reduced as much as possible.
Finally, I would like to add that it is not really conducive to a good marriage/relationship to deny your partner these needs for months or years. Perhaps you can find another time, for example at nap time, when you can separate yourselves from your child.
